# reversed Arabic when printing PDF

Tags: java, unicode, pdf-generation, arabic

I'm trying to print Arabic in some PDF documents using the Java code found here :
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/PDF-RTF/ArabicTextinPDF.htm

The example works great, except that the text comes out backwards. For example, changing the example slightly :

```
String txt = "\u0623\u0628\u062c\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629";
System.out.println(txt);
g2.drawString(txt, 100, 30);
```

What is printed on the screen are the same characters but in the opposite direction, compared to the PDF. The console output is correct, the PDF is not.

I don't want to simply reverse the characters because otherwise I would lose bi-directional support ...

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, iText supports Arabic shaping at a highler level than `drawString`.  Lets see here...

Ah!  `ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte canvas, int alignment, Phrase phrase, float x, float y, float rotation, int runDirection, int arabicOptions)`

Alignment is one of `Element.ALIGN_*`.  Run direction is one of `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_*`.  Arabic options are bit flags, `ColumnText.AR_*`

That should do the trick, with one caveat: I'm not sure that it'll handle multiple directions in the same phrase.  Your test string has CJKV, Arabic, and Latin characters, so there *should* be two direction changes.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, here is the complete process :

```
document.open();
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font("times", 0, 30);
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphicsShapes(PageSize.A4.width(), PageSize.A4.height());
g2.setFont(font);
String txt = "日本人 أبجدية عربية Dès Noël où";
System.out.println(txt);
java.awt.font.FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
java.awt.font.TextLayout layout = new java.awt.font.TextLayout(txt, font, frc);
layout.draw(g2, 15, 55);
g2.dispose();
document.close();
```

You'll notice it does multiple languages with bi-directional support. Only thing is it's impossible to copy/paste the resulting PDF text, as it is an image. I can live with that.

Comment: Actually, its PATHS.  This could result in a horrifically bloated PDF depending on how much text you run through this method.  PS: That is some Old Code.  Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode Arabic (or anything else) is always in logical order in a Java program. Some PDFs are made in visual order, though this is quite rare in the modern world. The program you cite might be a hack that ends up with PDF's that work, sort of, for some purposes.

If I were you, I'd start by examining some PDF's produced in Arabic by some modern tool.

This sort of 'graphics' approach to PDF construction seems risky to me at best.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it is rather hackish. Problem is, all of the other tools I have seen will not do the proper ligatures (?) between the letters. Also the letters will change appearance slightly depending on word placement and this is another issue I've come across with various other libs. So far this is the closest I've found to something that renders properly. If you know of any good libs in Java, PHP or python that can handle Arabic properly, I am all ears.